# How to send parameter to Query stored procedure and return to Gridview in Web (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, gridview

Environment: SQL Server 2012, Visual Studio 2012

Purpose: users fill the textbox and click the query button, Gridview will show the results.

This is what I think:

ASP:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myAsystemstring %>" SelectCommand="BasicinfoBuyersName" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
   <SelectParameters>
      <asp:Parameter Name="buyername" Type="String" />
   </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:TextBox ID="TxtboxQuery" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="BtnQuery" Text="Query" runat="server" OnClick="BtnQuery_Click"/>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" 
              AutoGenerateEditButton="True">
</asp:GridView>
```

C#:

```
protected void BtnQuery_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack != false)
    {
        if (TxtboxQuery.Text != "")
        {
            SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters.Add("buyname", TxtboxQuery.Text);
            GridView2.DataSourceID = SqlDataSource2;
        }
    }
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[BasicinfoBuyersName]
@buyername varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.BasicBuyernamesTable 
    WHERE [buyer] LIKE '%' + @buyername + '%'
END
```

I am new to B/S development. I don't know if there is other better way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove below if you adding select parameter by the code

```
<SelectParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="buyername" Type="String" />
</SelectParameters>
```

now

```
SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters.Add("buyername", TxtboxQuery.Text); 
// parameter name should equal to what you have in Stored procedure
GridView2.DataSource = SqlDataSource2;
GridView2.DataBind();
```

Or you can do the same without code by using `ControlParameter`

```
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TxtboxQuery" Name="buyername"  Type="String" />
</SelectParameters>
```

Comment: @HenryLee yes, I just copied your code, that need to be changed as `DataSource`, I'm glad that you able to find solution.